# How to delete echo commands to set Ubuntu's opening directory that were incorrect?

Tags: windows, bash, ubuntu, terminal, echo

I redownloaded Ubuntu on Windows 10 and I was resetting the root directory that is opened when Ubuntu is launched by calling

```
echo "cd ~/../../mnt/c/Users/jilli/Desktop" >> ~/..bashrc
```

However, the first couple times I called this I wrote the wrong directories. Therefore, there are 5 lines at the top of Ubuntu every time I open it trying to get into these directories stating "No such file or directory" which I have pasted below. How do I delete these calls?

```
-bash: cd: /home/jpenfield/Desktop/: No such file or directory
-bash: cd: /home/jpenfield/mnt/c/Users/jilli/Desktop: No such file or directory
-bash: cd: /home/jpenfield/mnt/c/Users/jilli/Desktop: No such file or directory
-bash: cd: ~home/jpenfield/mnt/c/Users/jilli/Desktop: No such file or directory
-bash: cd: /home/jpenfield/home/jpenfield/mnt/c/Users/jilli/Desktop: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

Open ~/.bashrc in your preferred text editor and remove the lines that you don't need.

For example,

```
$ nano ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much

Answer (score -1):

Just edit the file

```
vi ~/..bashrc
```